# Why is this error showing when trying to import a constant from another file in typescript?

Tags: typescript, import

I am trying to import a constant which is a JSON body from a file inside another folder inside my project.
I have tried copying the relative path to it and the constant has the export keyword before the declaration so I have export constant = {}

In the main file I am getting the Cannot find module error and I am running out of ideas as I have tried looking on google for possible fixes.

[The files skeleton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igDbg.png)

```
**The import statement: **

import {post_next_questions_request_body} from '..post-calls-bodies/post-next-questions';
```

The error:

```
Cannot find module '..post-calls-bodies/post-next-questions' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I have tried the following paths:
'..post-calls-bodies/post-next-questions'
'.post-calls-bodies/post-next-questions'
'post-calls-bodies/post-next-questions'

with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specified clearly which file you're writing the `import` statement in - I'm going to assume you're writing your import in `next-questions-api-tests`. I know I sound pedantic, but providing that level of textual explanation would make it easier for people to answer, since I had to open a picture in another tab to understand your question. Blind people cannot see that picture, and all of us can't copy and paste text from it.

Anyway, your syntax for relative paths is wrong (you need a slash after `..` or `.`, as in `../rest/of/the/path` and `./rest/of/the/path`).

Also, if my initial assumptions are right, the path itself is wrong: you need to go up two levels. Moving up once will put you in `tests` folder (just outside `API Tests` folder). Moving up once more will allow you then to go down inside `post-call-bodies`. In the end, you need:

```
import { post_next_questions_request_body } from '../../post-call-bodies/post-next-questions';
```

P.S.: If you don't have a good reason, calling a folder `API Tests` is not the best in my experience. What bothers me is the whitespace. It's a source of trouble in so many scripts and programs that if you don't really need it, something like APITests or (even better) api_tests would be more robust.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions Matteo, it is one of my first posts in here, your assumption was right the path provided works like a charm.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I've been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Either you didn't import it properly or you it should be

```
 import {post_next_questions_request_body} from '../post-calls-bodies/post-next-questions';
```

Make sure that the path is correct.

Comment: When copying the relative path of the file containing the constant I want to import I get this: post-calls-bodies\post-next-questions.ts , I tried this one too but it won't work either

Comment: Can you provide me with the full file ?